# Specifying model relationship as string vs concrete model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

Since Django provides two ways of specifying model relationship,

```
models.ForeignKey('User') vs models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Which one is more preferred and recommended? Is there any upside or downside of choosing one over the other?  In Django documentation, all the example are of the second form but I have seen many people specifying the relationship as a string.

Comment: In some situations you can not bring your models in an order that `User` is defined before and the name is not known yet. For this case the string version has been introduced.

Answer (score 0):

Both are fine. According to the situation's it is used.

```
class Application(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User')
    ...

class User(models.Model):
    ...
```

In the above example, the user model is defined below the application model. So Directly referring to `User` won't work.

```
class User(models.Model):
    ...

class Application(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ...
```

Here both the notations will work.